# Django using UpdateView within a detail view?

Tags: python, django, templates, detailview

I'm having issues with this update view:

```
class UpdateRules(UpdateView):
    model = BlackList
    fields = ['numkey','bnum','days','blocked']
    success_url='/'
```

I'm trying to create an edit form for each object in a list, which is itself on a detail view page. Here are the urls for both, starting with the detailview:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^update_rules/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$', UpdateRules.as_view(),name='update_rules'),
```

So the detail view page uses a slug for the object id. The context for the top level object is "instance", and the objects that i'm trying to update are 'obj'  so I assume when calling the updateview i need to do something like this:

```
{% for obj in instance.blacklist_set.all %}
            <li><a href="{% url instance.id 'update_rules' obj.pk  %}"><p style="font-size: 20px">{{obj.bnum}}</h2></a></li>
            <p>{{obj.pk}}</p>
{% endfor%}
```

I just keep getting "NoReverseMatch at /2/", when the the slug for the page is /2/. Have been trying lots of variations with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. The first parameter to the url tag is the name; why have you put that id there?

Comment: well, i figured I had to pass the slug for the object above it. For example, the url for the particular object that I'm doing the detail view for is at /2/. But that's probably wrong, when I remove it, it just gives me a 'NoReverseMatch at /2/' and says 'Reverse for 'update_rules' not found. '

Comment: You have a strange misconception here. URLs and views are not cumulative; one pattern points at one view. If you need your view to take an id for another object, you need to define that in the URL for that view, and then explicitly do something with it in that view.